# Is there a way to use flex charts in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, charts

Is it possible to put flex charts in a asp.net application?

Any other suggestion on easy to use chart controls, but fancy looking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.fusioncharts.com/Default.asp?Flex

Answer (score 1):

Try [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com). There's a special wrapper ASP.NET control too.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late but nevertheless

Try this: [www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/Flex_chart.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/Flex_chart.aspx)

Thanks,
Geeth